# Extract group of images from stack

Tags: matlab, median

I have a stack of images and I need a define, for each image, the substack defined by the neighbouring 10 (5 before and 5 after). The stack of images is defined as `IM(m,:,:)` (details below).

```
m = 0;
for j = 1:projections
    for k = 1:number_images
        u = sprintf('images_%03i_%05i.fits',j-1, k-1);
        IM(m,:,:) = fitsread(u);
    end
end
```

What I want to do is something like (code non working)

```
for k = 6:number_images
    rolling_interval_IM = [IM(k-5,:,:):IM(k+5,:,:)];
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: in the first code snippet,I think `m` should be initialized from zero and should be incremented in the inside loop. If not then your images will be overwriiten

Comment: also the total number of images seem to be `projections*number_images`. Hence in the second snippet iteration should be from `6:projections*number_images-5`. Also try `rolling_interval_IM = IM(k-5:k+5,:,:);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number_images = 60;
offset = 5;

for n=offset+1:1:number_images-offset
    rolling_interval_IM = squeeze(IM(n-offset:1:n+offset,:,:));        
end
```

You didn't say whether you wanted to store each rolling interval so this will just overwrite the previous.

It's a bit unusual I think to have the time dimension as your first dimension. That is normally the last in my experience.